# Check if there is a value from a string in the array, if not, then add it

Tags: c++, arrays, string

So, I have a lot of string that look like:

```
!,3,1,10,27,13,078,43,05,31,307,48,16,24,042,43,02,10,267,43
!,3,2,10,26,03,031,36,07,75,215,51,09,57,121,53,30,40,234,50
!,3,3,10,23,29,117,46,04,36,114,46
!,3,1,10,27,13,078,43,05,31,307,48,16,24,042,43,02,10,267,43
!,3,2,10,26,03,031,36,07,75,215,51,09,57,121,53,30,40,234,50
!,3,3,10,23,29,117,46,04,36,114,46
```

I need to print some values out of the line after a certain number of commas. But only if they appear for the first time. It is known that the number of values is less than 100. I have coped with the part of the code that outputs values from the line, but I cannot cope with the second part of the task. I created an array of 100 items and searched with the command std::find, and added a value if it was absent in the array, but the program output is wrong. Also I need to solve this task without using vectors :/

I've tried it this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    int k;
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream logs_("C:/Users/Ivan/Desktop/gpgga.txt"); 
    std::ofstream pout("C:/Users/Ivan/Desktop/outLOG.txt"); 


    int num = 100;
    int* Memory = new int[num];
    bool ExitFlag;

    if (logs_.is_open()) {
        while (getline(logs_, line)) {
            k = 0;
                for (size_t i = 0, N = 4; i < line.size(); i++) {
                    if (line[i] == ',') k++;
                    if (k == N) {
                        N += 4;
                        for (int f = 0; f < num; f++) {
                            if (Memory[f] != stoi(line.substr(i + 1, 2))) {
                                ExitFlag = false;
                                Memory[f] = stoi(line.substr(i + 1, 2));
                            }
                        }
                        if (ExitFlag == false) {
                            pout << "Satellite name: " << line.substr(i + 1, 2) << std::endl;
                        }
                    }
                }

            logs_.close();
            std::cout << "Success" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else std::cout << "File is not open" << '\n';
    pout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

But its output nothing

Here is another try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    int k;
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream logs_("C:/Users/Ivan/Desktop/gpgga.txt"); 
    std::ofstream pout("C:/Users/Ivan/Desktop/outLOG.txt"); 


    int array[100];
    int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);

    if (logs_.is_open()) {
        while (getline(logs_, line)) {
            k = 0;
            for (size_t i = 0, N = 4; i < line.size(); i++) {
                if (line[i] == ',') k++;
                if (k == N) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                        int* foo = std::find(std::begin(array), std::end(array), stoi(line.substr(i + 1, 2)));
                        if (foo = std::end(array)) {
                            pout << "Number: " << line.substr(i + 1, 2) << "  ";
                            array[j] = stoi(line.substr(i + 1, 2));
                        }
                    }
                    N += 4;
                }
            }
            logs_.close();
            std::cout << "Success" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else std::cout << "File is not open" << '\n';
    pout.close();

    return 0;
}
```

In theory program must output 27, 05, 16, 02, 26, 07, 09, 30, 23, 04

Current output: Number: 27  Number: 27  Number: 27  Number: 27  Number: 27 ... 100 times
Number: 05  Number: 05  Number: 05  Number: 05  Number: 05  Number: 05  Number: 05 ...100 times 
and they are repeated

Comment: Can we have a runnable example which shows the problem, and some more effort on your attempt, so we can fix it. It looks too much like "do my homework" at the moment. I'd recommend doing it with the standard library until the algorithm works, then replace it with older more error prone stuff.

Comment: You would need to extract needed column from each string (probably using regex or manual code) then use `std::unordered_set`, insert that number there and check if you got it the first time.

Comment: Please include your current output as well.

Comment: Try using an unordered map. Search for the value in the map and if it does not appear, add it to the map and print it out. If it does appear in the map, then skip it. [This geeksforgeeks.org page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/unordered_map-in-cpp-stl/) might give you some workable ideas.

Comment: @JoelTrauger do you mean set instead of map?

Comment: @Slava No I mean [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). Please see my links for more information.

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: @JoelTrauger what would you store as a value in `std::unordered_map` and why `std::unordered_set` is not sufficient?

Comment: @Slava Both will work, depending on the implementation. To store a value in the map you need to declare it as a type `unordered_map<int, int>` and then access it by writing `nameOfMap[number] += 1`. You asked if I meant set vs map and the answer was no. I fully intended to say "map".

Comment: @Joel, when I asked I meant unordered variants of set and map. What do you mean both will work, why do you need value from map?

Comment: @Slava read the documentation on both. Sets and maps provide similar functionality for this instance. In both cases you can store an item. The only difference is if the item is the key to a value or the value itself. It literally doesn't matter which OP uses, both have member functions that will allow him to search either for a duplicate. There is no benefit of one over the other for this case. You asked if I meant set vs map and the answer is no. I purposefully suggested a map per my own personal preference.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Added 2 runnable examples of programs and current output.

Comment: @JoelTrauger I do not need to read the documentation, I remember what they are, thats why I am asking why do you need map. "It literally doesn't matter which OP uses," it does matter, you should use container that fulfill the purpose, using `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` with empty or fake value is confusing and degrade readability of your program. You should not do that just because you like to use `operator[]`

Comment: @Slava If one is better wouldn't it be better to just say that instead? But we have wasted everyone's time with these needless comments. If a set is better for this task then it is better and you should say that up front.

Comment: @JoelTrauger set is not better or worse, it fits better when you just need to store a unique value (what is the OP case), map is "better" when you need associative array. I did not say up front because you may have something in mind that I did not understand that would make `map` more applicable. That's why I asked.

Comment: @Slava my initial thought was to increment the integer value of the mapping I suggested if a duplicate were found to provide a running tally of the numbers. However, the closer I look at a set, it provides the same functionality with less code so I concede that the set is actually better in all cases for this example. Initially however I did mean to suggest a map. You have changed my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user Slava std::unordered_set worked

```
#include <unordered_set>
...
    std::unordered_set<int> S;
    int t;
...
for (size_t i = 0, N = 4; i < line.size(); i++) {
                            if (line[i] == ',') k++;
                            if (k == N) {
                                t = stoi(line.substr(i + 1, 2));
                                if (S.find(t) == S.end()) {
                                    pout << "Number " << t << "  " << std::endl;
                                    S.insert(t);
                                }
```